# Is a naked char32_t signed or unsigned?

Tags: c++, c++11, char32-t

Similarly, is a naked `char16_t` signed or unsigned?  Is it implementation defined?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the standard (pre-C++11 draft n3290, or post-C++11 draft n3337) §3.9.1 *Fundamental types*:

> Types `char16_t` and `char32_t` denote distinct types with the same size, signedness, and alignment as `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`, respectively, in `<stdint.h>`, called the underlying types.

`uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t` are both unsigned (from §18.4.1 *Header `<cstdint>` synopsis*), so same for `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

Comment: Great!  Could you specify which draft you are referring to?  (N3337?)

Comment: I was looking at n3290, but n3337 has the same language exactly.